# Do not allow Index.html to be cached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, gruntjs

At the moment Index.html has a lot of JavaScript files that are concatenated and minified into one file whose name is later changed because of filerev grunt task.

Now this works as expected and the process is working just fine. Every time files are checked the name is changed and the new version of file is fetched from the server.

But the problem is when Index.html is cached, so it is pointing to the old JS file names after new deployment. How do we make sure that Index.html is always fetched from the server. Or at least if it is cached how to make sure to check every 15 minutes for new version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would manage such things on your webserver, but the easy way of doing it is adding these meta tags into your header:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```